# Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, plotly

I am running R Studio 1.0.136 on a Mac. When I try to run the code below I got an error

```
Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
```

I went by every thread here in stackoverflow, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187823/error-in-filecon-rb-cannot-open-the-connection-when-generating-a-plot-in) as well as I post questions on Coursera. I got no way to circumvent the problem. I even tried to move to Windows envoronment and got the same errors. I appreciate any help. 
The curious thing is that it runs from console but I got the error only when running knitr.
Thanks.

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
plot_ly(d, x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~carat, size = ~carat)
```

Just n case the markdown file is here [1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gg7bklr10n3ncfn/ERRORPA3.Rpres?dl=0).

Comment: Without seeing the knitr chunk(s) it's hard to say.

Comment: Is there a knitr log I can include to help? Please let me know how to pull it. The markdown file is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/gg7bklr10n3ncfn/ERRORPA3.Rpres?dl=0

Comment: Please include all relevant information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to resolve the issue: 
instead of choosing "New R Presentation" from the menu, choose "R Markdown" and from the popup window select "R Presentation". It's an odd workaround but worked for me and hopefully will work for you as well.

[image: file new menu]
[image: New Presentation]